# How to point /usr/bin/python to python2.6?

Tags: virtualbox, python, uninstall

I had done something like:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/704579/

I kind of want to undo that one.

While trying to remove virtualbox-ose I get the error saying

```
Removing virtualbox-ose ...
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                    [ OK ] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 2300, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 2294, in main
    rv = action.run(global_options)
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 1653, in run
    runtimes = get_installed_runtimes(with_unsupported=True)
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 278, in get_installed_runtimes
    default_version = pyversions.default_version(version_only=True)
  File "/usr/share/pycentral-data/pyversions.py", line 172, in default_version
    raise ValueError, "/usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to %s" % debian_default
ValueError: /usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to python2.6
dpkg: error processing virtualbox-ose (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 2300, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 2294, in main
    rv = action.run(global_options)
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 1477, in run
    runtimes = get_installed_runtimes()
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 278, in get_installed_runtimes
    default_version = pyversions.default_version(version_only=True)
  File "/usr/share/pycentral-data/pyversions.py", line 172, in default_version
    raise ValueError, "/usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to %s" % debian_default
ValueError: /usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to python2.6
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ose
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

There is a line which says **/usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to python2.6**

So my question is how to get /usr/bin/python to match the default version (python2.6)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have another version [i.e. 2.7] and also have 2.6 installed, I would do this:

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python
```

Then, python would be a symbolic link to python2.6

This is what you are asking, right? Or am I missing something here.

Comment: thanx this worked. :)